# How to build a secure (wss://...) websocket server using Kotlin's ktor?

Tags: kotlin, security, encryption, websocket, ktor

I've found documentation for an insecure ktor websocket server (ws://...):

https://ktor.io/docs/creating-web-socket-chat.html#creating-the-chat-client

I've found documentation for a secure ktor http server (https://...)

https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/main/codeSnippets/snippets/ssl-embedded-server

But I can't seem to find or figure out how to serve a secure ktor websocket server (wss://...)

I'd rather not use an SSL reverse proxy like nginx in front of it.

EDIT: Here's code:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.*
import io.ktor.network.tls.certificates.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import java.io.*

fun main() {
    val keyStoreFile = File("build/keystore.jks")
    val keystore = generateCertificate(
        file = keyStoreFile,
        keyAlias = "sampleAlias",
        keyPassword = "foobar",
        jksPassword = "foobar"
    )

    val environment = applicationEngineEnvironment {
        sslConnector(
            keyStore = keystore,
            keyAlias = "sampleAlias",
            keyStorePassword = { "foobar".toCharArray() },
            privateKeyPassword = { "foobar".toCharArray() }) {
            port = 8443
            keyStorePath = keyStoreFile
        }
        module(Application::module)
    }

    embeddedServer(Netty, environment).start(wait = true)
}

private fun Application.module() {
    install(WebSockets)
    routing {
        get("/") { // works at https://localhost:8443 in Firefox after approving cert
            call.respondText("This is https")
        }
        webSocket("/chat") { // fails at wss://localhost:8443/chat in Websocket js client with "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server"
            send("This is wss")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can configure it the same way as for an HTTP server. For more information read SSL and certificates documentation https://ktor.io/docs/ssl.html.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I've tried using sslConnector(...), which configures https and works, but doesn't seem to do anything for the websocket. I've added code in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using a self-signed certificate. I tried Chrome and set it to accept a self-signed certificate on localhost, which works. The error message Firebox provided suggested that a connection could not be established, when in fact it rejected the certificate.

A secure websocket server using ktor does in fact work like @AleksiTierman suggested. It is configured the same way as an https server.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with postman and works fine.
You can not use ws:// or wss:// protocols in browsers, use postman or other websocket clients instead.

Application.kt :

```
import com.example.plugins.configureRouting
import com.example.plugins.configureSerialization
import com.example.plugins.configureSockets
import io.ktor.network.tls.certificates.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.io.File


fun main() {
    val keyStoreFile = File("build/keystore.jks")
    val keystore = generateCertificate(
        file = keyStoreFile,
        keyAlias = "sampleAlias",
        keyPassword = "foobar",
        jksPassword = "foobar"
    )

    val environment = applicationEngineEnvironment {
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ktor.application")
        
        // no ssl, ws://127.0.0.1:6751
        connector {
            host = "127.0.0.1"
            port = 6751
        }
        
        // with ssl, wss://127.0.0.1:6752
        sslConnector(
            keyStore = keystore,
            keyAlias = "sampleAlias",
            keyStorePassword = { "foobar".toCharArray() },
            privateKeyPassword = { "foobar".toCharArray() }) {
            keyStorePath = keyStoreFile
            host = "127.0.0.1"
            port = 6752
        }

        this.module {
            configureSockets()
            configureRouting()
        }
    }

    embeddedServer(Netty, environment).start(wait = true)

/*
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 6752, host = "127.0.0.1") {
        configureSockets()
        configureRouting()
    }.start(wait = true)

 */
}
```

Sockets.kt :

```
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.websocket.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedReceiveChannelException
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.time.Duration


fun Application.configureSockets() {
    routing {
        this@configureSockets.install(WebSockets) {
            contentConverter = KotlinxWebsocketSerializationConverter(Json)
            pingPeriod = Duration.ofSeconds(3)
            timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(5)
            maxFrameSize = Long.MAX_VALUE
            masking = false
        }

        webSocket("/echo") {
            println("onConnect")
            try {
                for (frame in incoming) {
                    val text = (frame as Frame.Text).readText()
                    println("onMessage")
                    send(Frame.Text(text))
                }
            } catch (e: ClosedReceiveChannelException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                println("onClose ${closeReason.await()}")
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                println("onError ${closeReason.await()}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```